# Getting null for my profile serializer data instead of actual data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using Django-rest-auth to authenticate my users, that works well. how my model is set up is that I have the custom user model for authentication and I also have a profile model that gets created with a signal whenever a user is created.

I want that when the users are fetched in its URL, the profile for that user is also displayed, and I have passed through the serializer.

THE PROBLEM: I am getting null instead of the actual data

my models.py (I didnt include some models like the user managers, skill, e.t.c as i felt they werent relevant)

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['fullname']

    objects = UserManager()


class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profiles')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, verbose_name="DOB", null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    profile_photo = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300, null=True)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, related_name='skills')
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX, blank=True, null=True)
    type_of_body = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=BODYTYPE, blank=True, null=True)
    feet = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    inches = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    lives_in = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

the serializers.py code

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = "__all__"

        read_only_fields = ('pk',)


class CustomUserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    profiles = ProfileSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk', 'email', 'fullname', 'profiles')
        read_only_fields = ('email', 'fullname', 'profiles')
```

view.py

```
class ListUsersView(APIView):

    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request):
        user = User.objects.all()
        serializer = CustomUserDetailsSerializer(user, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^list-users/$', ListUsersView.as_view(), name='list-users'),
```

the JSON response I get

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "email": "opeyemiodedeyi@gmail.com",
        "fullname": "opeyemi odedeyi",
        "profiles": {
            "date_of_birth": null,
            "bio": null,
            "profile_photo": null,
            "sex": null,
            "type_of_body": null,
            "feet": null,
            "inches": null,
            "lives_in": null
        }
    }
]
```

how do I get the profiles to show in the response?

Comment: Why is everything in the `Profile`class surrounded by triple quotes?

Comment: it was a mistake formatting the question, but that isn't the problem

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is in your `CustomUserDetailsSerializer`. you have one-to-many relationship with User and Profile, but you are not explicitly telling it in your `profiles` attribute of the serializer. You have to pass `many=True` argument to the `ProfileSerializer`:

```py
class CustomUserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    profiles = ProfileSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk', 'email', 'fullname', 'profiles')
        read_only_fields = ('email', 'fullname', 'profiles')
```

But I am curious why you are using one-to-many relationship for that. You could use OneToOneField which explicitly tells that one user can only have one profile. But I am not familiar with your situation, so that is only my advice.